# TYPO3 backend can't delete record from own extbase extension

Tags: typo3, extbase

I create my first `Extbase` Extension in `TYPO3`. Everything works fine. I can create new records and show this records in frontend.

But i have two problems in Backend:

1. **Delete**

If i delete a record a javascript confirm box popup and ask me if i want to delete this record. If i click "Yes", the page reloaded but the record was not deleted. Also the `deleted` flag in the database was `0`

2. **Sorting**

If click to sort up or down my records i get the following error message

```
1: Attempt to move record 'dasdas' (tx_oaevents_domain_model_events:35) to after a non-existing record (uid=34)
```

The 'ctrl' **section of my TCA** looks like

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_oaevents_domain_model_events'] = array(
    'ctrl' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_oaevents_domain_model_events']['ctrl'],
.....);

  $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_oaevents_domain_model_events']['ctrl']['sortby'] = 'crdate DESC';
```

In the `TCA` i defined my sorting like this

How can i solve my issue?

Comment: How does the ctrl section in your TCA look like? The "sortby" option should be set to "sorting" and the "delete" option to "deleted". Do the fields "sorting" and "deleted" exists in your table?

Comment: @typoheads I edited my post with the ctrl section of my TCA. I have the field "deleted" in the table but not the field "sorting". Should i need the field "sorting" if i want to sort by "create" as i defined?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 2** stems from a very common mistake caused by two poorly named TCA `[ctrl]` properties. Those are [`sortby`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Ctrl/Index.html#sortby) (which you used) and [`default_sortby`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Ctrl/Index.html#ctrl-reference-default-sortby) (the one you meant).

As I‘d not rule out the possibility that problem 1 is somehow connected I suggest you fix `default_sortby` first and see what happens to delete behavior.

FYI: There‘s an [request](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/80178) to deprecate and rename one or both properties to avoid everyone stumble into the same pitfall.